# Traversing Through Object + Array + Object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Get guys,

I've tried looking through a bunch of tutorials but I can't seem to find one that covers this in detail. Maybe somebody could point me int he right direction.

I have a .json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Sabrina",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    }]
}
```

I want to run a .each loop and grab all of the users. Here's what I've tried:

```
$.getJSON("database.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.users, function(key, val) {
        $('.dbUL').append('<li>' + key + ' : ' + val + '</li>');
    });
});
```

So it looks like it actually does spit out the array since I get an output of 0 : [object Object] and 1 : [object Object].

My question is, how do I dig into the array and actually spit out the objects that I have stored in my array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing the properties what you want get (`fistName, lastName`): **[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ruyij/1/edit)**

```
$.getJSON("database.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.users, function(idx, val) {
        $('.dbUL').append('<li>' + val.firstName + ' : ' + val.lastName + '</li>');
    });
});
```

Not knowing the properties you want to get: **[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ruyij/2/edit)**

```
$.getJSON("database.json", function(data) {

    var LIhtml = "";

    $.each(data.users, function(idx, obj) { 

      LIhtml += "<li>";

      for(var key in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          LIhtml += obj[key]+" ";
        }
      } 

      LIhtml += '</li>';

    });

    $('.dbUL').append(LIhtml);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a fancy way to grab the values of a "Hash" in JS like you do in Ruby, for example.

Why not just using something like this below?

```
$('.dbUL').append('<li>' + key + ' : ' + val.firstName + ' ' + val.lastName + '</li>');
```